# Why request with ssl certification returns html?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, python-requests

i got a question

I'm trying to post some data to a webserver and get response. Webserver has SSL certificate verification, so i provide file for it. In the response i should receive xml file, but i receive some html.

My small script look like this:

```
import requests, sys, os

program_directory=sys.path[0]
verify = os.path.join(program_directory, "test.pem")
data='some data'

print requests.post('https://somewebsite', data=data, verify=verify).text
```

That's what i got before html:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py:251: SecurityWarning: Certificate has no `subjectAltName`, falling back to check for a `commonName` for now. This feature is being removed by major browsers and deprecated by RFC 2818. (See https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/497 for details.) SecurityWarning
```

If i use `verify=False` and don't provide file it works fine and returns proper data. What maybe a problem and why do i receive this warning and html?

Comment: Did you look at the HTML? There's a good chance it's an error page, indicating what's wrong.

Comment: I seems that `requests` (or `urllib3, rather) is complaining about an insecure certificate (see [this](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecurerequestwarning) ). Probably because it's self-signed (not verified by a trusted [certificate authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) ) You can always try to add your self-generated (I'm guessing you probably created a "local" certificate authority) to the certificate authorities used by urllib3 (check [this](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#using-your-system-s-root-certificates)  )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting [GrahamDumpleton](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/497#issuecomment-66942891):

> This is because in older Python versions the _ssl module does not return 'subjectAltName' in the set of fields in the SSL certificate. That the field isn't returned even if present means that even if the SSL certificate is valid, the check will fail and the warning logged.
>
> To eliminate the warnings you can disable urllib3 warnings globally.

The requests module contains a bundled version of urllib3, and you will most likely need to use:

```
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

If you want to ignore only that specific warning, you can use:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import SubjectAltNameWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(SubjectAltNameWarning)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your self signed certificate doesn't contain `subjectAltName`.

Use:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key myselfsigned.key -out myselfsigned.cer -days 365 -subj /CN=www.mysite.com
```

to generate the certificates.

Comment: It works! I think -subj param tells the client to check the requesting url with it.

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/523) this is a false warning that is generated if you are using Python2 2.7.2 or lower.

To ignore the warning, you may use the following from that link:

```
import requests
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warning():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
    requests.post(...)
```